# I can't figure out How to call previously created function inside another function?

Tags: javascript

Here is my example:
//This is my first function created and works just fine

```
function fullName(firstName, lastName){
  console.log(firstName +" "+ lastName);
}
fullName("Jason", "Doe");
```

//Below is my second function created after the first function and now I want to call "Jason, Doe 33" inside a fullNameAndAge function getting the Jason Doe form above function.

```
function fullNameAndAge(firstName, lastName, age){

    console.log(firstName +" "+ lastName +" "+ age);  
}
fullNameAndAge(fullName(), 33);
```

Comment: Returned values don't hang around. Once you call a function, it returns a value, without holding on to it. You can't call `fullName` without giving the two names, so `fullName()` doesn't make sense. You'd have to call `fullNameAndAge` like this in stead: `fullNameAndAge("Jason", "Doe", 33)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things wrong with this.

1. You aren't `return`ing anything from your functions.
2. `fullNameAndAge` expects 3 arguments passed to it. Even if `fullName` returned something, it would only be passing 2 arguments to `fullNameAndAge`
3. You aren't passing anything to `fullName` inside of your `fullNameAndAge` call.

#### Edit

Your code should look like this:

```js
function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    
    fullName("Jason", "Doe");
    
    
    function fullNameAndAge(fullName, age) {
        console.log(fullName + " " + age);
    }
    
    fullNameAndAge(fullName("Jason", "Doe"), 33);
```

Comment: Your explanation was great! I added some code for clarity.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked the question differently, seems like people didnt really understood what I wanted

Comment: @agzamovich You stated your problem clearly and the problems were obvious. No worries

Comment: @agzamovich is there something with Joe's code that you don't want it to do? I'm not sure what data type you are looking to get returned and what you expect to be sent. You could return an array from fullName and destructure it in your fullNameAndAge function

Comment: @jas7457 Take a look at @PM 77-1 answer. You'll notice that he didn't change the function signatures. It seems as though @agzamovich liked the function signatures, but wasn't sure about how to make `fullNameAndAge()` call `fullName()`

Comment: Honestly, I am kind of new to the javascript and I will accept the easier way to do it. Joe's code was simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call one function from another then just simply do it.

Something like thisL

```js
function fullName(firstName, lastName){
  console.log(firstName +" "+ lastName);
}

function fullNameAndAge(firstName, lastName, age){
    fullName(firstName, lastName);
    console.log(age);  
}
fullNameAndAge('John', `Doe`, 33);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the first function inside the second function then you can put it inside that function:

```
function fullNameAndAge(firstName, lastName, age) {
    fullName(firstName, lastName);
    console.log(firstName +" "+ lastName +" "+ age);  
}
fullNameAndAge("Jason", "Doe", 33);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were after?

```
function fullName(firstName, lastName){
  return (firstName +" "+ lastName);
}

function fullNameAndAge(firstName, lastName, age){

   return fullName(firstname, lastname)+" "+ age);  
}
fullNameAndAge("Jason", "Doe", 33);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. I will try to articulate as best I can what you are doing wrong and possible methods to fix.

First, You are calling fullName without its arguments here:

```
fullNameAndAge(fullName(), 33);
```

Once you define a function as taking a certain amount of arguments, you (generally speaking) always want to call it with those arguments.

Second, the function fullName does not return anything, it only calls console.log. In order for you to use the return value of fullName in fullNameAndAge, you must return the values from fullName. One suggestion would be

```
function fullName(firstName, lastName){
  return { firstName, lastName };
}
```

Here we are returning an object literal with the keys firstName and lastName mapping onto the values contained therein. We can now access this from fullNameAndAge:

```
function fullNameAndAge(fullNameObj, age){
  console.log(fullNameObj.firstName +" "+ fullNameObj.lastName +" "+ age);  
}
```

So we can now call it like this:

```
fullNameAndAge(fullName("Jason", "Doe"), 33);
```

```js
function fullName(firstName, lastName){
  return { firstName, lastName };
}

function fullNameAndAge(fullNameObj, age){
  console.log(fullNameObj.firstName +" "+ fullNameObj.lastName +" "+ age);  
}

fullNameAndAge(fullName("Jason", "Doe"), 33);
```

Comment: I am kind of new to the javascript and wanted to make it look as simple as possible. I know there are several ways to do it though

Comment: Yep that's perfectly fine. Honestly returning a string makes more sense in the context of your question anyway. I would however highly recommend learning about object literals if you are new to them, they are very fundamental to javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer